# Write python environmental variables to a javascript file

Tags: javascript, python, heroku, stripe-payments

I'm using [Heroku](http://heroku.com) and [Stripe](http://stripe.com) in a Python codebase.

There are different api keys stored in the `.env` file and not directly in a javascript file. Yet my `stripe.js` requires these keys.

I can access the keys in python, but my goal is to output a javascript constants file that contains this environmental variable so different deploys can use the different versions of the API key.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access environment variables using:

```
import os
os.environ['THE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME']
```

Regarding your particular use case, you could:

- Dedicate an URL to distributing the key and having clients hit that URL to retrieve it (do it once).
- Declare the variable somewhere else that is available to the browser (like, your base HTML template).
- Generate the full JS file on-the-fly at an URL (using a template to actually write JS and inject the key into it)

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for a solution that generates the JS on the fly. Do you know of any python libraries or code examples that does it this way?

Comment: @EvanHammer What web framework and template engine are you using? Basically, you just need to define an URL at `mysite/assets/stripe.js`  which will return the Javascript that you would render using a template engine similarly to what you'd do with an HTML file (Remember, however, to set appropriate headers).

Comment: I'm using tornado for both the web framework and template engine. I don't want to regenerate the `constants.js` file on each request.

Comment: @EvanHammer Why not? Do you have a specific requirement for not doing so? If performance is a concern, there will be plenty of time to optimize when you need to scale. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: fair. let's say i'm generating this js file. Is there a good python library for generating valid js or would you recommend just using a template and being smart?

Comment: @EvanHammer Unless the key might contain special characters, just using a template engine should be OK. if you want to be on the safe side, have a look at [the source of django's `escapejs` function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/html.py#L62), which applies several escapings defined a few lines above.